# SKScene to SKScene nil issues while unwrapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, skscene

If you guys have any questions (maybe i'm not giving enough information) I'll gladly show more of what I have, thank you so much

So I have conditionals inside of my gamescene that checks if x or y won and it should take you to another Scene using this piece of code:

```
let gameSceneTemp = GameScene(fileNamed: "thescene") self.scene?.view?.presentScene(gameSceneTemp!, transition: SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0))
```

I have no syntax issues but when I run it and play the game until the condition runs true, I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

on this line of code in the same class but in the didMove function

```
oScore = self.childNode(withName: "oScore") as! SKLabelNode
```

the didMove is setup as follows:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has similar issue make sure when you do let x = GameSccene, the file has to be a gameScene LOL Mine was a SKSccene so I switched to that and it works now